# Check if parent dict is not empty and retrieve the value of the nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's suppose that I have a nested dictionary which looks like that:

```
parent_dict = { 'parent_key': {'child_key': 'child_value'}
```

How can I write the following code:

```
if parent_dict.get('parent_key') is not None and parent_dict['parent_key']['child_key']=='value_1':
    print('Value detected')
```

in a more efficient way in terms of readability and amount of code?

Specifically I think that the first if condition could be somehow integrated with the second one in one condition.

So for I would like it to be like that:

```
if condition_x:
    print('Value detected')
```

where `condition_x` checks both if the `parent dict` is not empty and if not then it returns the value of the `child dict` otherwise it returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
if parent_dict.get('parent_key', {}).get('child_key') == 'value_1':
    ...
```

`dict.get(key)` will return `dict[key]` if the key exists; otherwise it will return `None`.`dict.get(key, default)` will return `default` if the key does not exist. setting the default value to an empty dict `{}` will make the second `.get` work.

Comment: I cannot see where you access the `'child_key'` - check also my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `key in dict`:

```
if 'parent_key' in parent_dict and parent_dict['parent_key']['child_key'] == 'value_1':
    print('Value detected')
```

Comment: cool but what does this change? check also my edited post. I want one condition ideally.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Your edit poses a different question than the original.

Comment: The original had also this sentence `Specifically I think that the first if condition could be somehow integrated with the second one.` so it is the same.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit My bad I missed it, I was initially concerned with `parent_dict.get('parent_key') is not None`.

Comment: No worries ;) !