# Safe get when parent is null in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to safe get a value from a nested dictionary.

`.get()` will give `None` if the value is not present in a dictionary but if a value is `None` `None.get("value_2")` will throw an error.

Sample Dictionary:

```py
  [
    {
      "value": {
        "value_2": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": null
    }
  ]
```

When iterating through the array for 0th element let us say `a` `a.get("value").get("value_2")` will give `string` as output, but for the second element `a.get("value").get("value_2")` gives an error. There needs to be a check `if value is None`, if not only then get `value_2`

Is there any way to skip the if check and make python return `None`. If the dictionary is nested for more than one level then I will have to check for `None` at multiple levels.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729154/check-if-parent-dict-is-not-empty-and-retrieve-the-value-of-the-nested-dict/57729194#57729194

Comment: Just use a default value of empty dict in your first get : `a.get("value", {}).get("value_2")`

Comment: @Guillaume that will not work a.get("value") will only return {} is value is not present not if value is None.

>>> a={"value":None}
>>> print(a.get("value",{}))
None

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It will not work because of the sample code above. In my case the key is present but it is None.

Comment: ok, reopened your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement function like below

```py
vals = [
    {
      "value": {
        "value_2": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": None
    }
  ]



def get_from_dict(dict_, path):
  path = path.split("/")[::-1]

  dict_ = dict_.get(path.pop())
  while dict_ is not None and len(path)>0:
    dict_ = dict_.get(path.pop())

  return dict_


for a in vals:
  print(get_from_dict(a, "value/value_2"))
```